# How to search for text in entire IntelliJ project?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm looking to replace every instance of a variable in my IntelliJ project. I know that it is present in quite a few files within the project, but I can't find a way to find them all. Is the some way to search for a variable in all of the files I have at once? I am on Windows.

Comment: To lookup any action or shortcut in IntelliJ, press Ctrl+Shift + A to open the [Find Actions](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tips/find-actions/) dialog and filter as you type ([FAYT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_search)). From the filtered results you can use arrow-keys to select the action and press enter to launch it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to open the [*Find in Files*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html?keymap=primary_windows#find_in_project) modal dialog and search all file contents.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
to open the [*Replace in Path*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html?keymap=primary_windows#replace_search_string_in_project) modal dialog.

See: [Search and replace a target within a project | IntelliJ IDEA Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html?keymap=primary_windows).

Comment: This is doing a textual search, it's not aware of whether the string represents that variable.

Answer (score 1):

While the cursor is on the variable,
press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> or from the main menu, select **Refactor | Rename** action.

IntelliJ IDEA will search and rename other code-occurrences automatically. It can also rename those occurrences in comments, strings and texts if wanted.

See: [Rename refactorings | IntelliJ IDEA Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/rename-refactorings.html)